# What are some practical applications of taking the vertical sum of a binary tree

Tags: sum, binary-tree

I came across this interview question and was wondering why you would want to take the vertical sum of a binary tree. Is this algorithm useful?

http://www.careercup.com/question?id=2375661

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a balanced tree the vertical sum could give you a rough insight into the range of the data.  Binary trees, although easier to code, can take on more pathological shapes depending on the order in which the data is inserted. The vertical sum would be a good indicator of that pathology.

Look at the code at [vertical sum in binary tree](http://algorithmsandme.in/tag/vertical-sum-of-nodes/).  This algorithm is written assuming a max width for the tree.  Using this algorithm you will be able to get a feel for different types of unbalanced trees.

An interesting variation of this program would be to use permutations of a fixed data set to build binary trees and look at the various vertical sums. The leading and trailing zeroes give you a feel for how the tree is balanced, and the vertical sums can give you insight into how data arrival order can affect the height of the tree (And the average access time for the data in the tree). An internet search will return an implementation of this algorithm using dynamic data structures.  With these I think you would want to document which sum included the root node.

Your question "Is this algorithm useful?" actually begs the question of how useful is a binary tree compared to a balanced tree.  The vertical sum of a tree documents whether the implementation is closer to O(N) or O(log N).  Here is an article on [balanced binary trees][3]. Put a balanced tree implementation in your personal toolkit, and try to remember if you would use a pre-order, in-order, or post-order traversal of the tree to calculate your vertical sum.  You'll get an A+ for this question.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this!